# How do I avoid duplication of code using AASM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

So I have in my project multiple models where many of them have an activate and deactivate function, which I manage using AASM

```
aasm column: 'status' do
  state :active, :initial => true
  state :inactive

  event :deactivate do
    transitions :from => :active, :to => :inactive
  end

  event :activate do
    transitions :from => :inactive, :to => :active
  end
end
```

I would like to avoid having duplication of this code, it is in 4 different models and I will probably not add any more states to them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could create module with this part and put it to `models/concerns/` or `lib/` folder (or somewhere else, just make sure that you have uploaded it):

```
  module ActivateDeactivateStatuses
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      aasm column: 'status' do
        state :active, :initial => true
        state :inactive

        event :deactivate do
          transitions :from => :active, :to => :inactive
        end

        event :activate do
          transitions :from => :inactive, :to => :active
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

and in your models:

```
  include ActivateDeactivateStatuses
```